# Headless Chrome not loading page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless

Headless Chrome does not load the page and gets stuck at:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".price-link:nth-child(1) .team-name")))
```

Why is it doing this? Is this a bug as it works perfectly in normal chrome and prints h below except in headless...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/soccer?LeftNav')
print('?')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".price-link:nth-child(1) .team-name")))

print('h')
```

Another example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()
import time
driver.get('https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/soccer?LeftNav')
import time
time.sleep(10)

langs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".price-link:nth-child(1) .team-name")
langs_text = []

for lang in langs:
    print(lang.text)
    langs_text.append(lang.text)

print('h')
```

Job prints with removed wait until though nothing is scraped. Page not loading is likely issue.

Comment: What are going to do next with this element?

Comment: @DebanjanB Scrape the page. Quite difficult as page doesn't load in headless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following code:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".price-link:nth-child(1) .team-name")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: It actually gets stuck at waiting for the element to appear so this doesn't help sadly.

Comment: @TheGman, what is happening if you changed to `EC.element_to_be_clickable`?

Comment: Stuck at wait again with that change.  There is something strange going on with headless Chrome and this page.